# Agile Central Basic App Settings

Tags: rally, code-rally

I'm implementing a simple app based on the UserIterationCapacity using a Rally.app.TimeboxScopedApp.

Now I want to specify a couple of settings as App settings and found the developer tutorial for this: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/settings

But I just cant get it working. Whenever I try to fetch a setting my code stops without any warnings.

I've implemented the following:

```
config: {
    defaultSettings: {
        hoursPerSp: 6,
        decimalsOnHoursPerSp: 1
    }
},

getSettingsFields: function() {
    return [
        {
            name: 'hoursPerSp',
            xtype: 'rallynumberfield'
        },
        {
            name: 'decimalsOnHoursPerSp',
            xtype: 'rallynumberfield'
        }
    ];
},
```

Now I'm trying to use

```
this.getSettings('hoursPerSp');
```

but unfortunately it is not working.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I needed to keep track of my scope, i.e., I needed to pass in the *this* variable to my renders.